# date format change in php after import from excel

Tags: php

I'm using an import of data from excel to mysql with php.

My issue concerns the date format i get from excel to my php array. for the excel date format d/m/Y the value i get in my array is different instead for the date format YYYY-mm--dd the value i get doenn't change.

[image]

So i have tried to change the date format on php like below

```
$realDate = "01-01-19";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($realDate));
```

i get as outpout 19-01-2001 while the right output must be 01-01-2019.
I would like to store the date in mysql in one single format whatever the date format on the initial import data

Comment: Well, how do you "get from excel to your PHP array"?

Comment: i'm using PHPExcel libr